# database file not showing in app_data in asp.net mvc4 tutorial using visual studios 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm doing this tutorial on ASP.NET: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4 and I reached a stage in which I need to work with a database.

Since I'm using Windows XP, LocalDB is not an option, so I configured SQL Server Express instead.

The app is working, but I can't seem to see the `MovieDBContext.mdf` file in the `App_Data` folder.
I tried refreshing, building, running, nothing helps.

The only thing in that folder is `ASPNETDB.mdf`. Does this file contain what I'm looking for?

I opened it and it showed a bunch of tables related to users of the app.

My problem comes when it's time to add new fields to the movie class and coordinate it with the database, meaning I have to turn on migration.

Here are the instructions for migration:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-new-field-to-the-movie-model-and-table

Sadly I cannot delete the database files according to this tutorial since I don't have access to the files.

Is there a way to see the `.mdf` files?

my connection string is:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Drivers;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: I edited the main question with the connection string.

Comment: 1.Search for "Movies.mdf" in File Explorer from root drive. Or 2.Search here: YourDrive:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\YourSqlVersion.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: Thanks, this helped, but there were still some problems. I gave up and switched to mvc 3 and SQL compact, and started the project from scratch. Too many problems, too little time, and now it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the order they come in your question

> The only thing in that folder is ASPNETDB.mdf. Does this file contain what I'm looking for?

Probably yes, it actually depends on the name you gave to the file when it was created.

Your Connection String

> Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;

It looks for a file named Movies.mdf in the App_Data folder whereas your file is names ASPNETDB.mdf, either rename the file to Movies.mdf or change the connection string

> Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late for almost 9 years, I took a nap :)

I had the same problem. It might be silly but took me almost 2 hours to figure it out.

By default, App_Data folder does not show files inside it. Somehow, they are hidden.

See image to show all files :)
[image]